# Understanding RS Component's "Program Memory Size"

Tags: microcontroller

When looking at RS Components' website, for example [this link](http://za.rs-online.com/web/c/semiconductors/processors-microcontrollers/microcontrollers/?sort-by=P_breakPrice1&sort-order=asc&sort-option=Price&applied-dimensions=4294965605,%204294487269,%204294510056,%204294487473,%204294481746,%204294505201,%204294503493,%204294821500,%204294877671,%204294879417,%204294505181,4294508091&lastAttributeSelectedBlock=4294511734)

they indicate *Program Memory Size* as two figures for a microcontroller:

[image]

Why are there two figures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably one is program memory (Flash) and the other is RAM. But some of the figures are clearly transposed so don't trust those listings. Look at the manufacturer's own data for the part number(s) you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they're reporting all nonvolatile memory as "program memory" for these chips. In reality, the larger figure is for the actual code (flash) memory, while the smaller figure (usually 256 bytes) is for EEPROM, which is actually nonvolatile data memory.